# writing data into multiple sheets in a single csv file from python/scrapy(python framework)

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am using scrapy framework and fetched data from two urls by creating two spider files.

Now for example when i run the `spider1` for `url1` the data scraped will be saved in to `csv1` file, when i run the second `spider2` the data will be saved in to `csv2` file.

Actually what i am trying to do is saving all the data from different spiders in to a single csv file in different sheets(sheet name should be as spider name)

```
All about my question is how to write data in to multiple sheets in a single csv file from python
```

**pipeline.py**

```
from w3c_browser.items import WCBrowserItem
import csv
from csv import DictWriter
from cStringIO import StringIO
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy import log

class W3CBrowserPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        self.brandCategoryCsv = csv.writer(open('wcbbrowser.csv', 'wb'))

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.started_on = datetime.now()
        if spider.name == 'browser_statistics':
            log.msg("opened spider  %s at time %s" % (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
            self.brandCategoryCsv = csv.writer(open("csv/%s-%s.csv"% (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')), "wb"),
                       delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        elif spider.name == 'browser_os':
            log.msg("opened spider  %s at time %s" % (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
            self.brandCategoryCsv = csv.writer(open("csv/%s-%s.csv"% (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')), "wb"),
                       delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        elif spider.name == 'browser_display':
            log.msg("opened spider  %s at time %s" % (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
            self.brandCategoryCsv = csv.writer(open("csv/%s-%s.csv"% (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')), "wb"),
                       delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if spider.name == 'browser_statistics':
            self.brandCategoryCsv.writerow([item['year'],
                                            item['internet_explorer'],
                                            item['firefox'],
                                            item['chrome'],
                                            item['safari'],
                                            item['opera'],
            ])
            return item

        elif spider.name == 'browser_os':
            def process_item(self, item, spider):
                self.brandCategoryCsv.writerow([item['year'],
                                                item['vista'],
                                                item['nt'],
                                                item['winxp'],
                                                item['linux'],
                                                item['mac'],
                                                item['mobile'],
                ])
                return item

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        log.msg("closed spider %s at %s" % (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
        work_time = datetime.now() - spider.started_on
        print str(work_time),"Total Time taken by the spider to run>>>>>>>>>>>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a nifty built in way to do this using scrapy from the command line.  But it is pretty simple to create your own [pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).  The pipeline could open the same file for all your spiders and write a different sheet for each different spider.  This would require you to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: yeah right thats what i am looking for, i am getting data in pipeline.py file and stuck near logic to implement this can u please just have a basic code on how to do this with csv's  ? or can i paste my pipeline.py code here

Comment: @shivakrishna it would be helpful if you could post your code in your question

Comment: I have pasted my pipeline.py code above. In that it will create a individual csv file with spider name and write data according to individual spider. All my intention is instead of creating another csv file with for another spider, i want to write the data of another spider in to the same csv file but in another sheet. If more than 2 spiders are there,then that should write data in to next  sheet and so on....... Can u please help me out by editing the above code in order to save data coming from all spiders into single csv file but in different sheets according to spider name.